# Django: Accessing for loop variable in the child template

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates

I have a base template:

```
base.html:

    {% for object in object_list %}  
            {%block object_attributes%} {%endblock%}
    {% endfor %}
```

and a child that inherits from it:

```
child.html

{% extends "base.html" %}

{%block object_attributes%} 
          {{block.super}}
          <td>{{ object.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ object.address }}</td>
{%endblock%}
```

It seems however, that the child is unable to see the variable "object". I understand it's a local variable of the for loop, but how could I still make it visible for the child?

Comment: because there are other things in the loop I did not write here that repeat between many templates.

Comment: You may consider writing a context processor for this

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I have to save the loop variable first to pass it to the child:

base.html:

```
{% for object in object_list %}  
            {% with object as object_pass %}  
            {%block object_attributes%} {%endblock%}
            {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

child.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{%block object_attributes%} 
      {{block.super}}
      <td>{{ object_pass.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ object_pass.address }}</td>
{%endblock%}
```